# How can I do more accurate calculation ln(1+x) in verliog

Tags: verilog

I want to calculate ln(1+x)in verilog A.
I know that the code is

> `y = ln(1+x);`

But if the x value becomes very small(ex x=3.52e-18), the y value becomes zero.
In MATLAB, I can calculate like

> `y=log1p(x);`

and I want to calculate like that code.
How can I calculate more accurately?

Comment: Is it for a test bench or rtl?

Comment: it is for test bench

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to add math functions that are not part of the IEEE standard are by using the C interface.

In SystemVerilog, you can add this line and not have to write any C code

```
import "DPI-C" function real log1p(real arg);
```

But in Verilog, you would have to call a VPI wrapper function that called `log1p` from code that you would have to write in C.

Answer (score 1):

You can always write a polynomial or rational or [table-driven](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/98267.98294) approximation to log1p, or find a library where someone else already implemented it, of course.

**But there's a cheap trick to compute log(1 + ) given  in a pinch if you already have a function to compute log()!**

1. If `1 + x = 1`—that is, if fl(1 + ) = 1—then just return .
2. Otherwise, evaluate `x*log(1 + x)/((1 + x) − 1)` (with exactly that parenthesization in the denominator).

---

**Why does this work?**

- For the easy case of || > 1/2, this works because fl(1 + ) only loses at worst a single bit of precision from , so the quotient /(fl(1 + ) − 1) essentially cancels (or exactly cancels, if  ≤ −1/2 or  ≥ 1) leaving essentially only log(fl(1 + )) ≈ log(1 + ).
- For the interesting case of ulp(1)/2 < || ≤ 1/2, this works because our approximation factors into ⋅() where () := log(1 + )/ is very well-conditioned near zero so that we still get a good approximation to () even if we actually evaluate (fl(1 + ) − 1).
  So while `log(1 + x)` alone magnifies the rounding error in `1 + x`,
  `x*log(1 + x)/((1 + x) - 1)`
  gives a good approximation to log(1 + ), within a handful of ulps (provided your `log` function has small error).

  Details:

  1. The absolute error of fl(1 + ) − 1 from  is at most ulp(1)/2.
  2. () ≥ 1/2 for all || ≤ 1/2.
  3. |′()| ≤ 2 for all || ≤ 1/2.

  Hence by the mean value theorem there is some  between  and fl(1 + ) − 1 such that

  |() − (fl(1 + ) − 1)| = |′()⋅( − [fl(1 + ) − 1])| ≤ 2⋅|1 +  − fl(1 + )| ≤ 2⋅ulp(1)/2 = ulp(1),

  so that the relative error of (fl(1 + ) − 1) from () is |() − (fl(1 + ) − 1)|/|()| ≤ 2⋅ulp(1).
  And (fl(1 + ) − 1) is what `log(1 + x)/((1 + x) - 1)` approximates.

  (For positive inputs, |′()| ≤ 1/2 so the bound improves to ulp(1)/2.)
- The edge case where `1 + x = 1` happens if and only if || ≤ ulp(1)/2.
  When this holds, since log(1 + ) =  + O(²) the error of series truncation (specifically, at most ||/2 ≤ ulp(1)/4, if you look at the exact terms of the series) is no worse than a rounding error.
  This case must be treated specially in order to avoid dividing by zero given by `(1 + x) - 1`.

(This technique appears as Theorem 4 in Goldberg's infamous note on [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know about Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf).)